# php glob with GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_ONLYDIR

Tags: php, glob

I'm trying to use multiple patterns with glob, but only for directories. So i tried

```
foreach (glob("{*,../img/*}", GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir)
```

but it's empty and nothing happens

```
foreach (glob("../img/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir)
```

works as expected.

is there a way to find the directories with multiple patterns or do i have to start a second foreach-loop?

Comment: the first command works as expected for me.

Comment: the first or the second snippet? the first snippet doesn't return anything in my case

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Note: The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non GNU systems, like Solaris.

Comment: Works fine on Windows, PHP 5.5.9

Comment: @Khôi oh, it's SunOS, so it's simply because it's not available?

Comment: @sinini Yes, too bad for you I guess :( need to give credit to PHP documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: ok what a pity, thanks anyway, didn'think of a problem like that